# Reuse a method from another component

Tags: reactjs

I would like to pass the both states as the result of getSettings method in Settings component to Add component. Is there any way to do that without copying the method to the other component?

Thank you

**Settings component**

```
export class Settings extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
         languages: [],
         currencies: []
        };
    }

    getSettings() {
        fetch('/settings', {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then( ... )
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({
                currencies: json.currencies,
                languages: json.languages
            });
        })
    }
}
```

**Add component**

```
export class Add extends Component {
    displayName = Add.name

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    languages: [],
    currencies: []
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse my impassioned plea, but for the love of all that is sacred please don't use higher order component abstractions, render props, etc. This is a simple problem that deserves a simple solution. No magic required. No esoteric React knowledge required.

1. Refactor getSettings function out of components.
2. Make getSettings function accept a component parameter.
3. Inside getSettings function, replace all use of 'this' with the 'component' parameter
4. Import getSettings function into any component that will use it.
5. Pass the component instance to this function. Eg. getSettings(this)
6. Congratulations, you now have a reusable and independently testable function that any component (or anything else for that matter) can use as required.

   ```
   const getSettings = component => () => {
     // Do your fetch here, and in your last
     // .then(), just use 'component.setState'
     // instead of 'this.setState'

     // Simulate async
     setTimeout(() => {
       component.setState({
         name: component.name,
         currencies: "whatever",
         languages: "yep"
       });
     }, 1000);
   };

   export default getSettings;
   ```

It's as simple as that.

See https://codesandbox.io/s/mjmpw5k08y

### Edit

In hindsight, you could probably accept a callback function instead of component, or return a promise. Either of these would make this less coupled with React components. Untested code follows...

#### With callback

```
const getSettings = callback => {
  // Simulate async
  setTimeout(() => {
      callback({
      name: component.name,
      currencies: "whatever",
      languages: "yep"
    });
  }, 1000);
};
```

Usage

```
getSettings(this.setState.bind(this));
```

#### With callback

```
const getSettings = () => window.fetch
    .then(res => res.json());
```

Usage

```
getSettings().then(this.setState.bind(this));
```

Comment: @LambrosSymeonaki Simple is the best. Love it 

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two ways where you can share your states in `Settings`.

1. Using [Child as Function/Render Prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern.
2. Using the new [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

### Child as Function/Render Prop

you can simply pass the state into `this.props.children` or `this.props.render`.

```js
class Settings extends Component {
  state = {
    languages: [],
    currencies: []
  };
  getSettings = () => {
    // fetch('/settings', {
    //     method: 'get',
    //     headers: {
    //         'Accept': 'application/json',
    //         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    //     }
    // })
    // .then( ... )
    // .then(json => {
    //     this.setState({
    //         currencies: json.currencies,
    //         languages: json.languages
    //     });
    // })
    this.setState({
      currencies: ["Dollar", "Euro", "Won"],
      languages: ["English", "French", "Korean"]
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSettings();
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children(this.state)}</div>;
  }
}
```

And use it like this.

```js
const renderComponents = (currencies, languages) => {
  const currencyItems = currencies.map(currency => (
    <li key={currency}>{currency}</li>
  ));
  const languageItems = languages.map(language => (
    <li key={language}>{language}</li>
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>currencies</h3>
      <ul>{currencyItems}</ul>
      <hr />
      <h3>languages</h3>
      <ul>{languageItems}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const AppChildAsFunction = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Using Child as Function</h2>
    <Settings>
      {({ currencies, languages }) => renderComponents(currencies, languages)}
    </Settings>
  </div>
);
```

### Using the new React Context API

Create and export new Settings provider, and consumer

***SettingsContext.js***

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

const defaultValue = {
  currencies: ["Dollar", "Euro", "Won"],
  languages: ["English", "French", "Korean"]
};
const { Provider, Consumer: SettingsConsumer } = React.createContext(
  defaultValue
);

class SettingsProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    languages: [],
    currencies: []
  };
  render() {
    return <Provider value={this.state}>{this.props.children}</Provider>;
  }
}

export { SettingsProvider, SettingsConsumer };
```

And the usage is about the same

***App.js***

```js
import { SettingsProvider, SettingsConsumer } from "./SettingsContext";
...
const AppWithContext = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Using Context API</h2>
    <SettingsConsumer>
      {({ currencies, languages }) => renderComponents(currencies, languages)}
    </SettingsConsumer>
  </div>
);
```

You can just pick and choose whichever one suits your taste.

**Working Demo on CodeSandBox**.
[image: Edit so.answer.51549396]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

High order component is good for this case. First you create method `withSetting` .

```js
export const withSetting = (Component) => class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
       languages: [],
       currencies: []
      };
  }
  getSettings() {
      fetch('/settings', {
          method: 'get',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
      })
      .then( ...)
      .then(json => {
          this.setState({
              currencies: json.currencies,
              languages: json.languages
          });
      })
  }
  render() {
    return <Component getSetting={this.getSetting} {...this.state} />
  }
}
```

And in `Add` Component. You can call `this.props.getSetting` or use `this.props. languages` and `this.props. currencies`

```js
import {withGetSetting} from './withGetSetting'

class Add extends React.Component {...}

export default withSetting(Add)
```

You can read about HOC here https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: @SungKim, your answer and this one are both useful as hell! Thank you so much. And I was telling maybe Redux is a suitable way! I should study more.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like below, not sure how and where you are rendering `<Add>` Component:

```js
export class Settings extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      languages: [],
      currencies: []
    };
  }

  getSettings() {
    return fetch('/settings', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(...)
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          currencies: json.currencies,
          languages: json.languages
        });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        { this.getSettings() && <Add { ...this.state}/> }
      );
    }
  }
```

In your `<Add>` Component, just read from `props` in its render method.